# min3d loading objects with just colors no texture imgs. color wont load

Tags: min3d

I am trying to load my 3D object in android . i tried mat-d's tutorial and it worked. now I am trying to load other object (example a cake with color) that has no image textures. the problem is the object will load but the color will not

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in your question that you don't have an image texture which i am guessing as the mtl file. In min3d you need to put in both the obj file as well as the mtl file in order to load the object correctly. So either you will have to create an mtl file or download another sample which has an mtl file.
I have followed the example from mat-d's tutorial and was able to load obj files correctly. Also make sure that you put the jpeg file in the drawable folder and set the path in mtl file correctly.